# How to add limit on records of table in angular 2

Tags: angular2-directives

This is the html where table structure is made with the help of helper components. As in BookingRow selector rowData is used as attribute and in 
Booking I am getting the listing of booking. So it is showing 10 records.
I want to display only 5 record so how to do this in angular 2.

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h3>Today's Bookings</h3>
    <div>
        <table width="100%">
            <thead BookingHeadings type="provider"></thead>
            <tbody BookingRow pageType="provider dashboard" [rowData]="Bookings" pricingColumnStatus=false></tbody>      
      </table>
      <div><a [routerLink]="['/provider/bookings/todays']">
        <button type="button" value="View all">View All</button></a>
      </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your [rowData]=“Bookings“ is an Array. And I also guessing you get the Bookings from some kind of http service. So you can in the Success callback slice the Array.

```
var onlyFiveBookings=Bookings.slice(0,5); // for the first five.
```

I think a better way is to change it server side so that the response would only contain 5 bookings.

Comment: this.bookingService.getTodayBookings()
         .subscribe(res => {this.Bookings = res},
                    err => console.log(err),
                    ()  => console.log("Successfull"));  This is the service response so how do i use it here.

Comment: this.Bookings=res.slice(0,5);